# Can't install lubuntu: Overflow error

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, 18.10

I’m trying to install lubuntu on an old gateway Nv53a laptop, and no matter what options I choose it eventually gets to `673569] ehci-pci 0000:00:12.2: dma_direct_map_sg: overflow 0x000000106a6f000+2048 of device mask fffffffff`. The number to the left of the string goes in a loop from 100,000-999,999 then back to 1000,000 (taking about 1.2 seconds to do a loop). I’ve tried `nomodset`, `noapic`, `acpi=off` and even `forcepae` but it always gets to the same endless loop.

Memory test is in progress with no problems so far.

Here’s a picture:
[image: pic]
Memory test so far with additional info:
[image: memtest]

Answer (score 0):

I recognized it as some sort of memory overflow, so I removed one of the sticks of ram (making it 2 GB instead of 4 GB). Once I did that it booted up fine!